# What is the default page orientation?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have seen that if Ignore Pagination is selected shows the whole document in a single page in JasperReports. For example, if there are 5000 rows, it shows in a single page in report if Ignore Pagination is selected.

Now, When we print that using frontend Java does JasperReports engine prints in landscape or portrait by default?

Is there any default format (Portrait or Landscape) if Ignore Pagination is selected when we print that page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ***Portrait*** orientation is default. And it is not depends on *ignorePagination* property.

#### The facts about default orientation

1) It is set as default in *jasperreport.xsd* file.

The snippet from *jasperreport.xsd* of *JasperReports 6.2.0* version:

```
   <attribute name="orientation" use="optional" default="Portrait">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>Page printing orientation.</documentation>
    </annotation>
    <simpleType>
     <restriction base="string">
      <enumeration value="Portrait">
        <annotation>
            <documentation>Portrait page layout.</documentation>
        </annotation>
      </enumeration>
      <enumeration value="Landscape">
        <annotation>
            <documentation>Landscape page layout.</documentation>
        </annotation>
      </enumeration>
     </restriction>
    </simpleType>
   </attribute>
```

2) In *net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport* class is set as default.

The snippet from the *JRBaseReport* class for the same (*6.2.0*. The all below code is the same) version:

```
protected OrientationEnum orientationValue = OrientationEnum.PORTRAIT;
protected WhenNoDataTypeEnum whenNoDataTypeValue = WhenNoDataTypeEnum.NO_PAGES;
protected SectionTypeEnum sectionType = SectionTypeEnum.BAND;
```

3) If we are talking about export to *xls* format, we can find this piece of code in the *net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter* class:

```
protected void createSheet(CutsInfo xCuts, SheetInfo sheetInfo) {
    sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetInfo.sheetName);
    patriarch = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    HSSFPrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup();
    printSetup.setLandscape(pageFormat.getOrientation() == OrientationEnum.LANDSCAPE);
```

4) If we are talking about export to *pdf* format, we can find this piece of code in the *net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter* class:

```
protected void setPageSize(JRPrintPage page) throws JRException, DocumentException, IOException {

//  some piece of code is omitted
    Rectangle pageSize;
    switch (pageFormat.getOrientation()) {
    case LANDSCAPE:
        // using rotate to indicate landscape page
        pageSize = new Rectangle(pageHeight, pageWidth).rotate();
        break;
    default:
        pageSize = new Rectangle(pageWidth, pageHeight);
        break;
    }
    document.setPageSize(pageSize);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation